# Unable to docker-compose up postgres with docker-entrypoint-initdb.d on MacOS

Tags: postgresql, docker, macos, docker-compose

Attempt to run the docker-compose on MacOS seems to be having issues mounting the init.sh file when troubleshooting the logs throws "ls: reading directory '/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/': Operation not permitted". Tried running this on a different OS seems to work fine.
[Error MSG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHCMq.png)

Current OS & CHIP: MAC - Apple M2 Max

The docker-compose.yml file looks like this:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:14
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    volumes:
      - ./db:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
```

The init.sh file looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 --username "$POSTGRES_USER" --dbname "$POSTGRES_DB" <<-EOSQL
        CREATE USER docker;
        CREATE DATABASE docker;
        GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE docker TO docker;
EOSQL
```

The docker version:

```
Client:
 Cloud integration: v1.0.35
 Version:           24.0.2
 API version:       1.43
 Go version:        go1.20.4
 Git commit:        cb74dfc
 Built:             Thu May 25 21:51:16 2023
 OS/Arch:           darwin/arm64
 Context:           desktop-linux

Server: Docker Desktop 4.21.1 (114176)
 Engine:
  Version:          24.0.2
  API version:      1.43 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.20.4
  Git commit:       659604f
  Built:            Thu May 25 21:50:59 2023
  OS/Arch:          linux/arm64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.6.21
  GitCommit:        3dce8eb055cbb6872793272b4f20ed16117344f8
 runc:
  Version:          1.1.7
  GitCommit:        v1.1.7-0-g860f061
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just mount `init.sql` file instead of `init.sh` and contents of the file to be

```
    CREATE USER docker;
    CREATE DATABASE docker;
    GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE docker TO docker;
```

bash script file will be owned by `root` and user `postgres` wont have permissions to execute it otherwise use `postgres:14-buster` image

Comment: I tried removing postgres_user for default root access, change the init.sh to .sql following your example above and also tried using postgres-buster image resulting the same error. 

In addition, my Full Disk Access is also enabled.

Comment: @sandwichielim What error did you get when you used `.sql` file?